# Substitute a version in json with jsonbuilder in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How to replace the version from "**1.0.2**" to "**2.6.5**" in a json file "**deploy.json**" using groovy scripting, and the file content has been provided below.

```
{
  "versions": [
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "replian"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "hp"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "shutoff"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "spark"
        }
            ]
}
```

I've tried the below, but getting an error;

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def content = """
{
  "versions": [
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "replian"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "hp"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "shutoff"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "spark"
        }
            ]
}"""

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped) 
builder.content.versions.find{it.version}.version = "2.6.5"
println(builder.toPrettyString())
```

**The issue is:**
Only first conf "replian" version is getting replaced when i use the above script;

```
{
    "version": "2.6.5",
    "conf": "replian"
},
{
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "conf": "hp"
},
{
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "conf": "shutoff"
},
{
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "conf": "spark"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [collect](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html) method

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def content = """
{
  "versions": [
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "replian"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "hp"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "shutoff"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "spark"
        }
            ]
}"""

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped) 
builder.content.versions.collect{ it.version = '2.6.5' }
println(builder.toPrettyString())
```

Output

```
{
    "versions": [
        {
            "version": "2.6.5",
            "conf": "replian"
        },
        {
            "version": "2.6.5",
            "conf": "hp"
        },
        {
            "version": "2.6.5",
            "conf": "shutoff"
        },
        {
            "version": "2.6.5",
            "conf": "spark"
        }
    ]
}
```